# Accessing k8s cluster with service account token

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

Is possible to gain k8s cluster access with serviceaccount token?

My script does not have access to a kubeconfig file, however, it does have access to the service account token at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token.

Here are the steps I tried but it is not working.

1. kubectl config set-credentials sa-user --token=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)
2. kubectl config set-context sa-context --user=sa-user

but when the script ran "kubectl get rolebindings" I get the following error:
Error from server (Forbidden): rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test:default" cannot list resource "rolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" in the namespace "test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is possible to gain k8s cluster access with serviceaccount token?

Certainly, that's the point of a ServiceAccount token. The question you appear to be asking is "why does my `default` ServiceAccount not have all the privileges I want", which is a different problem. One will benefit from reading [the fine manual on the topic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#service-account-permissions)

If you want the `default` SA in the `test` NS to have privileges to read things in its NS, you must create a Role scoped to that NS and then declare the relationship explicitly. SAs do not automatically have those privileges

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: test-default
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: whatever-role-you-want
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: test
```

> but when the script ran "kubectl get pods" I get the following error: Error from server (Forbidden): rolebindings.rbac.authorization.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test:default" cannot list resource "rolebindings" in API group "rbac.authorization.k8s.io" in the namespace "test"

Presumably you mean you can `kubectl get rolebindings`, because I would not expect running `kubectl get pods` to emit that error

Comment: That was it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you; please mark the answer as accepted so others know your question was resolved

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. For instance, if you login K8S dashboard via token it does use the same way.

Follow these steps;

Create a service account

```
$ kubectl -n <your-namespace-optional> create serviceaccount <service-account-name>
```

A role binding grants the permissions defined in a role to a user or set of users. You can use a predefined role or you can create your own. Check this link for more info. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-example

```
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding <binding-name> --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=<namespace>:<service-account-name>
```

Get the token name

```
$ TOKENNAME=`kubectl -n <namespace> get serviceaccount/<service-account-name> -o jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}'`
```

Finally, get the token and set the credentials

```
$ kubectl -n <namespace> get secret $TOKENNAME -o jsonpath='{.data.token}'| base64 --decode
$ kubectl config set-credentials <service-account-name> --token=<output from previous command>
$ kubectl config set-context --current --user=<service-account-name>
```

If you follow these steps carefully your problem will be solved.

Comment: Where is this service account's token stored inside the container? I don't see another one under /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pick the correct secret as there are two different types for each sa:

- kubernetes.io/dockercfg
- kubernetes.io/service-account-token

The token you are looking for is in the latter.